# Are the D3DX or DXTK libraries sufficient for the streaming of Sparse Virtual Textures(Megatextures)?

Tags: c++, io, directx, textures

I'm trying to implement this technique in DirectX11: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=p49vOX-_LyU#! As far as I know, I have to do a pass where I only render the geometry and map their UV coordinates to a render target that is about 1/10 or 1/20 of the actual resolution.Maybe a RWTexture2D and then read it back on the CPU.However I don't understand what to do then as far as the streaming goes.How do I know about which model needs which megatexture.My question may sound a little confusing, maybe because I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing here.Any help would be appreciated.I read some papers about it and they suggested to use JPEG compression.I can work with several kinds of compression, but the main issue is I don't know how to quickly stream specific parts of the textures that correspond to the given UV coordinates.With the basic methods of loading textures(D3DX library and the DirectXToolkit library) even a 512x512 texture takes some noticeable time to load(when you load it there's a slight stutter), since after all it's limited to hard drive I/O speed.So I'm guessing the texture needs to be even smaller in size(extremely aggressive compression), but that's ok, I just need to figure out the..how you say - heuristics behind the paging.